# Add new row in grid table

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to add 5 new row when add button is triggered. I managed to add 5 new row when the first time user click the button. The second time user clicks should be 10 new row. But it will be 5 rows instead of 10. And Im using JSONModel. Thanks!

This is my view:

```
<table:Table id="idAccountingDataTable" rows="{oAccountingDataTable>/}" selectionMode="MultiToggle" visibleRowCount="7" ariaLabelledBy="title"
                                class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
                                <table:extension>
                                    <OverflowToolbar>
                                        <!--<Title id="title" text="Products"/>-->
                                        <ToolbarSpacer/>
                                        <Button icon="sap-icon://add" press="onPressAdd" type="Transparent"/>
                                        <Button text="{i18n>Delete}" press="onPressDelete" type="Transparent"/>
                                        <Button icon="sap-icon://upload" press="onPressUpload" type="Transparent"/>
                                    </OverflowToolbar>
                                </table:extension>
                                <table:columns>
                                    <table:Column width="25rem">
                                        <Label text="{i18n>Description}"/>
                                        <table:template>
                                            <Input value="{oAccountingDataTable>Description}"/>
                                        </table:template>
                                    </table:Column>
                                </table:columns>
                            </table:Table>
```

Controller:

```
onPressAdd: function () {
            var oEntry = {
                    Description: ""
                },

                oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oEntry);

            var oTable = this.byId("idAccountingDataTable");
            this.getView().setModel(oModel, "oAccountingDataTable");

            this._aAccountingDataTable = new Array(5);
            this._aAccountingData = [];
            this._aAccountingDataTable.forEach(function (oAccountingDataTable) {
                this._aAccountingDataTable.push(oEntry);
            }.bind(this));

            this.getModel("oAccountingDataTable").setProperty("/", this._aAccountingDataTable);
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, each time you press `onPressAdd` you create a new `sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel` with 5 entries and bind it to the Table. If the user edits the description of the 5 entries and presses the *add*-button the changes will be discarded by your coding and 5 blank entries will be shown.

---

Initialize your `sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel` in your `onInit` method:

```js
        onInit: function () {
            //Generate your JSONModel once upon initialization of the View
            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel([]);
            this.getView().setModel(oModel, "oAccountingDataTable");
        }
```

Manipulate the exting data in your `onPressAdd` method:

```js
        onPressAdd: function () {
            //Get your accountingmodel
            var oAccountingModel = this.getView().getModel("oAccountingDataTable");
            //Get existing entries
            var aExistingEntries = oAccountingModel.getData();
            //Create 5 new entries
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                aExistingEntries.push({
                    Description: ""
                });
            }
            //SET/Update entries
            oAccountingModel.setData(aExistingEntries);
        }
```

Comment: Yes its working now. Thanks. But is it possible if I still want to use forEach loop? Try to change from for loop to forEach loop..But its working weird.

Comment: If you use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) you would **loop over each entry in the array**. If the array has 5 entries, 5 new ones are created. If the array has 10 entries, 10 new entries are created. That's not what you wan't to achieve right ?

Comment: Yeah that is not what I want. Ok I guess need to stick with for loop. Thanks!